# Pass datas between routes angularjs/expressjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, express

I have a form, and when I submit it, another form is displayed with radio buttons which are other datas. I select one and submit it. I want the data to be displayed in another page but it doesn't display anything with what I've done.

So there is the /form route, and I want to be redirect on the /confirmation route with my datas after the last submit.

**Bellow is my formController in angularjs**

```
.controller('formController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'form';
    $scope.firstName = '';
    $scope.lastName = '';
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.departure = '';
    $scope.destination = '';
    $scope.submitFirstForm = function() {
        $http.post('/form', {
            firstName: $scope.firstName,
            lastName: $scope.lastName,
            email: $scope.email,
            departure: $scope.departure,
            destination: $scope.destination,
        }).then(function(res) {
            $scope.response = res.data;
            });
        }

    $scope.submitConfirmationForm = function(flight){

        $http.post('/confirmation', {
            departure: $scope.departure,
            destination: $scope.destination
        }).then(function(res) {
            $scope.otherResponse = res.data;
            $location.path("/confirmation");
            });

    };
}]);
```

**Bellow is my express post function only for the /CONFIRMATION route**

```
    app.post("/confirmation",function(req,res)
{
    var departure=req.body.departure;
    var destination=req.body.destination;

    otherResponse = {
        "confirmation": [{
            "departure": departure,
            "destination": destination,
            "msg": "MSG OK",
        }]
    };

    res.json(otherResponse);
});
```

**Finally, bellow my confirmation.html to see what is going on with my json otherReponse**

```
 <pre>
    {{otherResponse | json}}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the 'value', you need to do something like this:

$location.path('/confirm/').search({param: 'otherResponse'});

$location methods are chainable.

this produce :

/confirm/?param=otherResponse

Check the doc for [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)